how to add groups to "Run Only" flows without triggering the automated notification from Power Automate?
how to add groups to "Run Only" flows without triggering the automated notification from Power Automate to actual users members of the group?
I have like 50.000 users and I don't want to send an email notification to everyone in the group. How to prevent the notification being sent?

Power Automate sends a notification email to the users or groups added to the "Run Only" permissions. Unfortunately, there is no built-in feature to disable these notifications directly within Power Automate.
